# Why scikit-learn mlp training takes too much time?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network, mlp

I am trying to train a MLP using scikit-learn's MLPClassifier.

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
```

I am training the mlp with 5400 iterations but it takes approximately 40 minutes. What do I do wrong?
Here is the created mlp:

```
mlp= MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(128),activation='relu',solver='adam',batch_size=500,shuffle=False,verbose=True)
```

here is the training part of my code:

```
for j in range (5400):
    mlp.partial_fit(train_X, y_train,classes=np.unique(y_train))#1 step
```

train_X dimensions are (27000,784) which is 27000 samples and each sample is 28*28=784 pixels.

My processor is Intel i7-9750H RAM size is 16GB.

Comment: Check if more than one CPU core is used, use `fit` and change the  `max_iter` attribute, perhaps you don't need that many interations. If you are concerned about speed, use a GPU accelerated library.

Answer (score 3):

You don't train it for 5400 iterations, but for possibly up to ~ 1M ones; this is not the way to do it.

Checking the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html), you'll see that `MLPClassifier` has already a parameter `max_iter`, with default value 200 (which is the value used in your case, since you don't specify anything different):

> **max_iter: *int, default=200***
>
> Maximum number of iterations. The solver iterates until convergence (determined by ‘tol’) or this number of iterations. For stochastic solvers (‘sgd’, ‘adam’), note that this determines the number of epochs (how many times each data point will be used), not the number of gradient steps.

So, if every one of your 5400 iterations exhausts the 200 `max_iter`, you are actually doing 5400x200 ~= 1,000,000 iterations (epochs).

It's not clear why you choose to use a `for` loop with a `partial_fit`; you may want to either go for a full `fit` with `max_iter=5400` and no loop, or stay with your existing loop + `partial_fit` and change the definition of your `MLPClassifier` to `max_iter=1`.

In what you have shown, I cannot see any reason for the loop approach; it would be justified if your data could not fit to memory and you used it to feed different slices of your data per iteration, but as is it does not make any sense.

Comment: I changed max_iter to 1 but it is the same. I am using partial_fit to observe MLP behaviour.

Comment: @fierywasabi try `fit` without the loop; is it (significantly) faster?

Comment: Tried fit without the loop, processing time is exactly the same. Additionally, python uses 64% of CPU says task manager and all cores operate at 4,1GHz in this operation.

Comment: Update: After 1500 iterations, time between iterations got bigger and CPU usage rises up tp 98%. I really don't know where am I doing wrong.